# Pending Revocation

Tags: iphone

in ios provisioning portal the how can i remove the status of my certificate ??? currently it shows pending revocation..thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should contact Apple about that or wait. Some people over at [the Apple Forum](http://discussions.info.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=11214381) did have that problem last year and the solution war to wair

Comment: any other solution for that ? please tell me .